# How to set frame offset for source and reference video for calculating using FFMpeg commandline?

Tags: bash, command-line, ffmpeg, video-streaming, frame

I have a scenario where I am streaming a reference video on a server machine and receiving it at a client machine with exact same codec, using FFMpeg via UDP/RTP.

So, I have a reference.avi file and a recording.ts file with me. Now, due to a network side issue and FFMpeg discarding old frames, often the recording.ts lacks **exactly** 12 FRAMES from the beginning. Sometimes, it may lack more frames in-between but that'd due to general network traffic and packet loss reason and I don't plan to account for that. Anyways, due to those 12 frames, when I calculate the PSNR, it drops down to ~13, even though remaining frames may/may not be affected.

So, my aim is to discard first 12 frames from reference.ts and then compare. For that, I would also need to adjust the frames from recording.ts.

Consider the following scenario:

reference.ts has 1500 frames. So naturally I am going to cut-short it 1488. Then we have the following cases:

1. recording.ts has 1500 frames. This is not affected. Still I will remove 12 frames to match the count. So frame 1 would then represent frame 13.
2. recording.ts has 1496 frames. This is not affected. Still I will remove 12 frames even though it'd get to 1484 count assuming that frame 1 would then represent frame 13.
3. recording.ts has 1488 frames. This is affected. No need to remove frames.
4. recording.ts has 1480 frames. This is affected. No need to remove frames.

Once that is done, then I will calcualte the PSNR. So, my FFMpeg should be able to do all this, hopefully in a single command on bash.

A better alternative would be for FFMpeg to find the where the 13th frame is in recording.ts and then cut-short from the beginning. That'd be more preferred and even more if there is no cut-shorting required, i.e. if offset could be set in-line to command and no additional video output is generated for use in PSNR comparison.

Current I am using the following command to calculate the PSNR.

```
ffmpeg -i 'recording.ts' -vf "movie='reference.avi', psnr=stats_file='psnr.txt'" -f rawvideo -y /dev/null
```

It'd be great if somebody could help me in this regard. Thanks.

Comment: Are you transcoding the stream when receiving it?

Comment: I have copied the codec and PSNR shows no loss in general i.e. if I don't run it on that network.